# I need to modify the menu so that only one sub-menu is displayed at a time, in general so that no more than one menu can be displayed at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

When I select an option of the menu it is displayed as it should be but when I select another option the other option is also displayed, the idea is that only one is displayed at the same time.

[image]

`

```
$('.sub-menu ul').hide();
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("200");
    $(this).find("i.fa").toggleClass("fa-angle-up fa-angle-down");
});
```

`
this is the code that I have in jquery and I need a change so that it only allows me to display one option instead of two.

`

```
<nav class='animated flipInX'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class='fa fa-home'></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        About
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Products
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Services
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the html code, please help me :c
`

This is the html code, please help me :c

Comment: you should add a generic function "closeAll" which close all your submenus. In your click function, first step you call this closeAll. In add, you can test the element clicked before closeAll, if it's the submenu already opened you do nothing

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".sub-menu ul").hide()
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
  $(".sub-menu ul").not($(this)).hide();
  $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("200");
  $(this).find("i.fa").toggleClass("fa-angle-up fa-angle-down");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='animated flipInX'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class='fa fa-home'></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        About
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Products
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='sub-menu'>
      <a href='#'>
        Services
        <i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href='#'>
            Product Item
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        Contact Us
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you select the same one to open and close it, it does not close, that is, since you press the drop-down menu it will not close even if you press it again.